# How to make pizza that has a fat outer rim?

Tags: pizza, dough, crust

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shaping thick crust pizza dough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/shaping-thick-crust-pizza-dough)

When I make pizza, I stretch my dough to the wanted size and shape, with even thickness all around...
I'm finding it difficult to understand at which point I leave room for the outer rim...
As I see it, to make a outer rim that is fatter than the rest or the pizza I either:

1. Leave a thicker outer rim in the dough before putting it in the oven,
2. Roll the edges inwards to form the outer rim after I stretched the dough evenly, Or
3. Do nothing and simply leave the edges without sauce, and the crust will form by itself?

Which is it?

And in case it's the first one, how do I accomplish this while stretching the dough?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10273/shaping-thick-crust-pizza-dough

Comment: @ Jefromi There is a quality answer there too, but the question title here is more clear.

Comment: @Matt: Maybe it's more clear to you - not to me. In any case, the point of closing duplicate questions is to help let anyone searching for the same thing using different words find the single place for all the answers. If people want to close my question as a duplicate of this one, that's cool too, but they're definitely the same question.

Comment: This is fine by me as well... I'm all for creating an informative database of cooking information. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If by crust you mean a raised lip, simply pinch/push the edge up all the way around. Leaving the edge free of sauce won't make it rise a great deal more than the rest of the pizza.

Another way to get a lip is to first make a round, hemispherical mound of dough, like a D on its side. Form your hands into a circle and push them into the dough so you have a ring of dough surrounding a central mound, with a little dip in between the two. This ring is your crust.

Finally, push the pizza into shape, spreading the central mound of dough out to form the base, leaving the outer ring/crust in place.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the question to reflect what I was trying to ask...

Comment: No problem. Expanded my answer a little.